# Why is puppeteer not downloading or working in vscode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, node-modules

When I'm trying to install puppeteer, the terminal is stuck on this:

```
reify:puppeteer: timing reifyNode:node_modules/puppeteer-extra Completed in 54ms
```

and none of the commands work. If I enter, it just pastes the same line. Then when I make a new terminal and run the code, even though I've installed it multiple times, this comes up:

> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/aurora/Desktop/mainfiles/bot.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

Why is this happening? Also other modules import fine but it's puppeteer that's acting strangely. Thanks

Comment: I install puppeteer using `npm i puppeteer` in the cli or `yarn add puppeteer` if you're using yarn

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch the same thing happens but i get stuck on this
npm i puppeteer
⸨                  ⸩ ⠇ reify:puppeteer: sill audit bulk request {

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch macos